# OAuth2 Authorization and Resource server certificates

Tags: certificates, oauth, .net

I'm implementing a custom `IAuthorizationServerHost` using `DotNetOpenAuth` library.
[Example implementation](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios) uses two certificates for `CreateAccessToken` (see Listing 6):

```
public AccessTokenResult CreateAccessToken(
             IAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequestMessage)
{
    var token = new AuthorizationServerAccessToken();
    token.Lifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

    var signCert = LoadCert(Config.STS_CERT);
    token.AccessTokenSigningKey = 
             (RSACryptoServiceProvider) signCert.PrivateKey;

    var encryptCert = LoadCert(Config.SERVICE_CERT);
    token.ResourceServerEncryptionKey = 
             (RSACryptoServiceProvider) encryptCert.PublicKey.Key;

    var result = new AccessTokenResult(token);
    return result;
}
```

Where

> STS_CERT is created for signatures by the authorization server
>
> SERVICE_CERT is designed for decoding the resource server

Why different certificates are used? Is it secure to use only one instead of both STS_CERT and SERVICE_CERT certificates?

Comment: Based on your code the STS is cert+private key (so you can sign with it) but the SERVICE is "just" public certificate, so you do not have its private key.